# Parse std::string with Boost ptree

Tags: c++, boost

I have this code

```
std::string ss = "{ \"item1\" : 123, \"item3\" : 456, \"item3\" : 789 }";

// Read json.
ptree pt2;
std::istringstream is(ss);
read_json(is, pt2);
std::string item1= pt2.get<std::string>("item1");
std::string item2= pt2.get<std::string>("item2");
std::string item3= pt2.get<std::string>("item3");
```

That I need to parse a JSON string into `std::string`'s as shown above, I tried to put a catch statement here but the actual error is just `<unspecified file>(1):`

So I assume that the read_json is just reading file, not std::string, in what way that this `std::string` can be parsed?

Comment: *Where* do you get the reported error? Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, together with the actual and expected output?

Comment: By the way, I created an MCVE myself, [and it works fine](http://ideone.com/vuedE1). Maybe you have some other problem somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sample reads from a *stream* (that is "like a file", if you will). The stream has been *filled* with your string. So you're parsing your string. You can't directly parse from the string.

You could however use Boost Iostreams to read from the source string directly without a copy:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f43e84c56dc6491)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

namespace pt = boost::property_tree;

std::string ss = "{ \"item1\" : 123, \"item2\" : 456, \"item3\" : 789 }";

int main()
{
    // Read json.
    pt::ptree pt2;
    boost::iostreams::array_source as(&ss[0], ss.size());
    boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::array_source> is(as);

    pt::read_json(is, pt2);
    std::cout << "item1 = \"" << pt2.get<std::string>("item1") << "\"\n";
    std::cout << "item2 = \"" << pt2.get<std::string>("item2") << "\"\n";
    std::cout << "item3 = \"" << pt2.get<std::string>("item3") << "\"\n";
}
```

That will just copy less. It will not result in different error reporting.

Consider including line breaks in the string so the parser will report line numbers.